# How to get permission via Notification pop up once it's denied

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

If I don't allow the notification when it's prompting then if I try to call the same below method , it's not showing notification permission pop up.

```
 UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert]) {
                 (granted, error) in
                 if granted {
                     print("Notification permission Granted")
                 } else {
                     print("Notification permission Denied")
                 }
            }
```

How do I get the same pop up once permission is denied

Answer (score 0):

Take the user to application notification settings.

That's the only way

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!)
```

Comment: It's not straight forward for novice user. I would like one button  with pop up one the app like the usual request prompt.

Comment: You don't get a choice.  You can only show the Apple dialog once.  You can show your own dialog and open the app settings as shown in this answer if they want to change it.  You should improve your chances of the user allowing notifications by asking them when the request makes sense and they understand the context.  Don't simply ask for notification permissions as soon as they open your app for the first time